# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined when getting wcf response

Tags: jquery, ajax, wcf

My problem: I'm not able to read the property `length` when binding the Wcf Response, but I can get a response in the Wcf Service. The code below is for autocompletion in the textbox.

```
function AutoCompleteProjectName() {
    alert('AutoCompleteProjectName');
    var projectname = $('#<%= txtProject.ClientID %>').val();
    alert(projectname);

    $(".autosuggest").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
                    alert('ajax cal');
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        url: serviceUrl + "admin/AddTask.svc/AutoCompleteProjectName",
                        data: JSON.stringify({ "projectname": projectname, "empno": 1 }),
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                                response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                                        console.log("data" + JSON.stringify(item));
                                        return {                                          
                                            label: item.split('/')[0],
                                            val: item.split('/')[1]
                                        }
                                 }));
                        },
                        error: function (result) {
                                alert("Error");
                        }
                    });
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
                $('#<%= hdfldProjectId.ClientID %>').val(ui.item.val);
                var hd = $('#<%= hdfldProjectId.ClientID %>').val();
                alert(hd);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: where are you trying to access the property `length`